# Month wise % share of the Categories and not cumulative

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have a data where I want to calculate the % share of a category (Text column) however I want to exclude the blanks from the calculation and want to calculate the share month wise (Text column)

My query:

```
SELECT Category, Count(Category) AS CountOfCategory, Count([Category])/DCount("*","[Tablename]") AS MyPercent
FROM [Tablename]
GROUP BY Category;
```

Current sample outcome from the query looks like this.
[image: Access Query outcome]

My Table looks like this

```
| Month Text | Category |  
|------------|----------|  
| Dec'18     | A        |  
| Nov'18     | A        |  
| Dec'18     | A        |  
| Nov'18     | C        |  
| Dec'18     | A        |  
| Nov'18     | C        |  
| Dec'18     | B        |  
| Nov'18     | C        |
```

Please help.

Comment: And how did you get those 'blank' rows? Is there another table involved in the query? Post the SQL statement. What you want likely easier to accomplish in a report using Sorting & Grouping with aggregate calcs.

Comment: These the blank values in the same table where the category is not defined.

Comment: Your sample table does not have blanks. How do you get blanks in the query? So, is there another table involved? Edit question to post the query statement.

Comment: I am editing the Table sample to make it more clear.

Comment: SQL Code still missing! Avoid images show sample-data as text [Markdown Tables Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables)

Comment: My profile is not letting me put text. it is forcing me convert text as image.

Comment: You still have not posted the query statement. Have you considered instead of query, building a report and do calcs in report design? Apply filter to exclude the 'blank' records.

Comment: @Gopal - change your query view (directly under the **File** tab) to **SQL View** then copy the text, [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53847636/edit) above, then paste it in.

Comment: Done. I have added the query and converted the table as well

Comment: Format tables as code (indent 4 spaces) and convert images of output sample to text too. Format your SQL-Code too (e.g. [online-sql-formatter](https://www.sqlinform.com/online-sql-formatter/))

Comment: Well, that query will not produce that output from that data source.

Answer (score 0):

Your query doesn't match you data example but I guess this query should help:

```
SELECT a.[Month Text], a.Category, Count(a.Category),
Count(a.Category)/
    (
    SELECT Count(b.Category)
    FROM yourtablename AS b
    WHERE b.[Month Text] = a.[Month Text]
    )
FROM yourtablename AS a
WHERE a.Category Is Not Null 
AND a.Category<>""
GROUP BY a.[Month Text], a.Category;
```